# como podria mejorar este carousel multi item para que el codigo sea mas limpio?

Tags: bootstrap, angular, carrusel

tengo un carousel multi item y estoy vuelto un 8 para poder hacerlo funcionar ya que tiene 3 items por pasada, y lo unico que se me ocurre es generar una variable por cada item para poder mostrar las imagenes en cada uno de ellos ya que las imagenes las tengo en array. el problema es que cuando hago click en el boton "siguiente" o "anterior" todo el orden se me pierde.Estoy trabajando con Angular y Bootstrap. alguien me podria ayudar? este es mi código:

```js
import { Component, OnInit, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { HostlistService } from '../servicios/hostlist.service';

import { Inmueble } from '../modelos/inmueble';
import { mergeMap } from 'rxjs/operators';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-slider',
  templateUrl: './slider.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./slider.component.css']
})

export class SliderComponent implements OnInit {
  anterior: number=1;
  siguiente: number=1;
  z: number=0;
  a: number=1;
  b: number=2;
  c: number=3;
  d: number=4;
  e: number=5;


  band: boolean = false;

  url: string = "URL";

  constructor(public hostlistService: HostlistService) { }
  ngOnInit() {
    this.hostlistService.obtenerToken()
      .pipe(
        mergeMap(resultToken => {
          //do whatever you want to do with the token
          //i.e. Save the token in the localstorage like this -
          localStorage.setItem("token",resultToken.access_token);
          return this.hostlistService.obtenerInmuebles(resultToken);
        })
      )
        .subscribe(
          result => {
            this.cargarJson(result);
          },error =>{
            console.log(error);
          }
        );
    }

    /*this.hostlistService.getInmuebles().subscribe(
      result => {
        console.log("-----------_>"+result.data);
      },error => {
        console.log(error);
      }
    );*/

  /*
  anteriorInmueble(){
    (this.i<=0) ? this.i=680: this.i=this.i-5;
    console.log("AntIn VALOR DE I: "+this.i);


  siguienteInmueble(){
    (this.i>=680) ? this.i=0: this.i=this.i+5;
    console.log("SigIn VALOR DE I: "+this.i);
  }*/


// metodo para cargar el Json recibido de la petición
  cargarJson(result){
    var foto1,foto2: string;
    foto1 = "fot0", foto2 = "fot";
    var precio: number=0;
    var i,j: number=1;

                for(const item of result.data) {
                    var pos: number=0;          //variable que define la posicion a almacenar en el vector
                    pos =0;
                    console.log("POS----->"+pos);
                    var inmueble = new Inmueble();
                    inmueble.fotos = [];
                    inmueble.nombre = item.nomb_prod_c;
                    inmueble.id = item.id_c;
                    inmueble.estacionamiento = item.estan_c;
                    inmueble.baño = item.banof_c;
                    precio = item.price;
                    precio = Math.round(precio*100)/100;
                    inmueble.tipo = item.tipo_inmu_c;
                    inmueble.precio = precio;
                      (item.fot01_c != "") ? (inmueble.fotos[pos]="fot01_c", pos++): (inmueble.fotos[pos]="");
                      (item.fot02_c != "") ? (inmueble.fotos[pos]="fot02_c", pos++): (inmueble.fotos[pos]="");
                      (item.fot03_c != "") ? (inmueble.fotos[pos]="fot03_c", pos++): (inmueble.fotos[pos]="");
                      (item.fot04_c != "") ? (inmueble.fotos[pos]="fot04_c", pos++): (inmueble.fotos[pos]="");
                      (item.fot05_c != "") ? (inmueble.fotos[pos]="fot05_c", pos++): (inmueble.fotos[pos]="");
                      (item.fot01_c != "") ? (inmueble.fotos[pos]="fot06_c", pos++): (inmueble.fotos[pos]="");
                      (item.fot02_c != "") ? (inmueble.fotos[pos]="fot07_c", pos++): (inmueble.fotos[pos]="");
                      (item.fot03_c != "") ? (inmueble.fotos[pos]="fot08_c", pos++): (inmueble.fotos[pos]="");
                      (item.fot04_c != "") ? (inmueble.fotos[pos]="fot09_c", pos++): (inmueble.fotos[pos]="");
                      (item.fot05_c != "") ? (inmueble.fotos[pos]="fot10_c", pos++): (inmueble.fotos[pos]="");
                      (item.fot01_c != "") ? (inmueble.fotos[pos]="fot11_c", pos++): (inmueble.fotos[pos]="");
                      (item.fot02_c != "") ? (inmueble.fotos[pos]="fot12_c", pos++): (inmueble.fotos[pos]="");
                      (item.fot03_c != "") ? (inmueble.fotos[pos]="fot13_c", pos++): (inmueble.fotos[pos]="");
                      (item.fot04_c != "") ? (inmueble.fotos[pos]="fot14_c", pos++): (inmueble.fotos[pos]="");
                      (item.fot05_c != "") ? (inmueble.fotos[pos]="fot15_c", pos++): (inmueble.fotos[pos]="");
                      (item.fot01_c != "") ? (inmueble.fotos[pos]="fot16_c", pos++): (inmueble.fotos[pos]="");
                      (item.fot02_c != "") ? (inmueble.fotos[pos]="fot17_c", pos++): (inmueble.fotos[pos]="");
                      (item.fot03_c != "") ? (inmueble.fotos[pos]="fot18_c", pos++): (inmueble.fotos[pos]="");
                      (item.fot04_c != "") ? (inmueble.fotos[pos]="fot19_c", pos++): (inmueble.fotos[pos]="");
                      (item.fot05_c != "") ? (inmueble.fotos[pos]="fot20_c", pos++): (inmueble.fotos[pos]="");
                      if(pos == 0){
                        inmueble.fotos[pos]="n";
                      }
                    this.hostlistService.inmuebles.push(inmueble);  //se almacena el inmueble en el vector de inmuebles

            }
            this.band = true;
            console.log(this.hostlistService.inmuebles[350].nombre);



    }

    anteriorInmueble(){
      if(this.anterior%2==0 || this.siguiente%2==0){
        this.z=this.z-6;
        this.a=this.a-6;
        this.b=this.b-6;
        this.c=this.c-6;
        this.d=this.d-6;
        this.e=this.e-6;
      }
      console.log("--------ANTERIOR:"+this.anterior);
      this.anterior=this.anterior-1;

    }


    siguienteInmueble(){
      //(this.z>=680)?
    if(this.siguiente%2==0 || this.anterior%2==0){
      this.z=this.z+6;
      this.a=this.a+6;
      this.b=this.b+6;
      this.c=this.c+6;
      this.d=this.d+6;
      this.e=this.e+6;
    }
      console.log("--------SIGUIENTE:"+this.siguiente);
      this.siguiente=this.siguiente+1;

    }



  consultarPais(){

  }
}
```

```html
<div class="container" id="contenedor-global">
    <div class="d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center">

      <div class="d-flex align-items-center justify-content-center">
        <div> <span class="text-hot">
          <b>HOT</b> </span> </div>
        </div>
        <div id="div-redondo" class="d-flex ml-2 align-items-center justify-content-center">
          <div class="text-hot align-middle">
              list
          </div>
        </div>
    </div>


<div *ngIf="this.hostlistService.inmuebles && this.band ; else espera">

  <div class="carousel slide " data-ride="carousel" data-interval="false" id="multi_item">
    <div class="carousel-inner">
      <div class="carousel-item active">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-sm-4">
            <h1>valor de Z: {{z}}</h1>
            <div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
              <div class="" *ngIf="this.hostlistService.inmuebles[z].fotos[0]!=''; else sino">
                  <!-- <h1>{{inmuebles[z].nombre}}</h1> -->

                  <img class="card-img-top" id="imgPortada" src="{{url}}{{this.hostlistService.inmuebles[z].id}}_{{this.hostlistService.inmuebles[z].fotos[0]}}" alt="Card image cap">
              </div>
              <ng-template #sino>
                <img class="card-img-top" id="imgPortada" src="../assets/images/slider/3.jpg" alt="Card image cap">
              </ng-template>
              <div class="card-body ">
                <div class="">
                  <i class="fas fa-cart-plus "></i> <h6 class="d-inline-flex ml-2" >Precio1: {{this.hostlistService.inmuebles[0].precio | currency: 'USD'}}</h6>
                </div>
                <div class="">
                  <i class="fas fa-map-marker-alt"></i> <h6 class="d-inline-flex ml-2">Ubicacion</h6>
                </div>
                <div class="">
                  <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal">Ver detalles</button>
                </div>
              <!-- Modal -->







              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-sm-4">
            <h1>valor de A: {{a}}</h1>
            <div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
              <div class="" *ngIf="this.hostlistService.inmuebles[z+1].fotos[0]!=''; else sino">
                  <!-- <h1>{{inmuebles[z+1].nombre}}</h1> -->
                  <img class="card-img-top" id="imgPortada" src="{{url}}{{this.hostlistService.inmuebles[a].id}}_{{this.hostlistService.inmuebles[a].fotos[0]}}" alt="Card image cap">
              </div>
              <ng-template #sino>
                <img class="card-img-top" id="imgPortada" src="../assets/images/slider/3.jpg" alt="Card image cap">
              </ng-template>

              <div class="card-body">

                <div class="d-inline-flex">
                  <i class="fas fa-cart-plus"></i><h6>Precio: {{this.hostlistService.inmuebles[a].precio | currency: 'USD'}}</h6>
                </div>
                <div class="d-inline-flex">
                  <i class="fas fa-map-marker-alt"></i><h6>Ubicacion</h6>
                </div>
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal">Ver detalles</button>
              <!-- Modal -->

             <app-modal [tipo]="this.hostlistService.inmuebles[a].tipo" class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true"> </app-modal>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-sm-4">
            <h1>valor de B: {{b}}</h1>
            <div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">

              <div class="" *ngIf="this.hostlistService.inmuebles[b].fotos[0]!=''; else sino">
                <!-- <h1>{{inmuebles[z+2].nombre}}</h1> -->

                  <img class="card-img-top" id="imgPortada" src="{{url}}{{this.hostlistService.inmuebles[b].id}}_{{this.hostlistService.inmuebles[b].fotos[0]}}" alt="Card image cap">
              </div>
              <ng-template #sino>
                <img class="card-img-top" id="imgPortada" src="../assets/images/slider/3.jpg" alt="Card image cap">
              </ng-template>
              <div class="card-body">
                <div class="d-inline-flex">
                  <i class="fas fa-cart-plus"></i><h6>Precio: {{this.hostlistService.inmuebles[b].precio | currency: 'USD'}}</h6>
                </div>
                <div class="d-inline-flex">
                  <i class="fas fa-map-marker-alt"></i><h6>Ubicacion</h6>
                </div>
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal">Ver detalles</button>
              <!-- Modal -->
              <app-modal [tipo]="this.hostlistService.inmuebles[b].tipo" class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true"  > </app-modal>

              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>


      <div class="carousel-item">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-sm-4">
            <h1>valor de C: {{c}}</h1>
            <div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">

              <div class="" *ngIf="this.hostlistService.inmuebles[c].fotos[0]!=''; else sino">
                <!-- <h1>{{inmuebles[z+3].nombre}}</h1> -->

                  <img class="card-img-top" id="imgPortada" src="{{url}}{{this.hostlistService.inmuebles[c].id}}_{{this.hostlistService.inmuebles[c].fotos[0]}}" alt="Card image cap">
              </div>
              <ng-template #sino>
                <img class="card-img-top" id="imgPortada" src="../assets/images/slider/3.jpg" alt="Card image cap">
              </ng-template>

              <div class="card-body">
                <div class="d-inline-flex">
                  <i class="fas fa-cart-plus"></i><h6>Precio: {{this.hostlistService.inmuebles[c].precio | currency: 'USD'}}</h6>
                </div>
                <div class="d-inline-flex">
                  <i class="fas fa-map-marker-alt"></i><h6>Ubicacion</h6>
                </div>
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal2">Ver detalles</button>
              <!-- Modal -->
              <app-modal [tipo]="this.hostlistService.inmuebles[c].tipo" class="modal fade" id="exampleModal2" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true"> </app-modal> -->

              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-sm-4">
            <h1>valor de D: {{d}}</h1>
            <div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">

              <div class="" *ngIf="this.hostlistService.inmuebles[z+4].fotos[0]!=''; else sino">
                <!-- <h1>{{inmuebles[z+4].nombre}}</h1> -->

                  <img class="card-img-top" id="imgPortada" src="{{url}}{{this.hostlistService.inmuebles[d].id}}_{{this.hostlistService.inmuebles[d].fotos[0]}}" alt="Card image cap">
              </div>
              <ng-template #sino>
                <img class="card-img-top" id="imgPortada" src="../assets/images/slider/3.jpg" alt="Card image cap">
              </ng-template>

              <div class="card-body">
                <div class="d-inline-flex">
                  <h6>Precio: {{this.hostlistService.inmuebles[d].precio | currency: 'USD'}}</h6>
                </div>
                <div class="d-inline-flex">
                  <i class="fas fa-map-marker-alt"></i><h6>Ubicacion</h6>
                </div>
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal2">Ver detalles</button>
              <!-- Modal -->
              <app-modal [tipo]="this.hostlistService.inmuebles[d].tipo" class="modal fade" id="exampleModal2" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true"  > </app-modal>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-sm-4">
            <h1>valor de E: {{e}}</h1>
            <div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">

              <div class="" *ngIf="this.hostlistService.inmuebles[e].fotos[0]!=''; else sino">
                <!-- <h1>{{inmuebles[z+5].nombre}}</h1> -->

                  <img class="card-img-top" id="imgPortada" src="{{url}}{{this.hostlistService.inmuebles[e].id}}_{{this.hostlistService.inmuebles[e].fotos[0]}}" alt="Card image cap">
              </div>
              <ng-template #sino>
                <img class="card-img-top" id="imgPortada" src="../assets/images/slider/3.jpg" alt="Card image cap">
              </ng-template>

              <div class="card-body">
                <div class="d-inline-flex">
                  <i class="fas fa-cart-plus"></i><h6>Precio: {{this.hostlistService.inmuebles[e].precio | currency: 'USD'}}</h6>
                </div>
                <div class="d-inline-flex">
                  <i class="fas fa-map-marker-alt"></i><h6>Ubicacion</h6>
                </div>
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal">Ver detalles</button>
              <!-- Modal -->
              <app-modal [tipo]="this.hostlistService.inmuebles[e].tipo" class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true"> </app-modal> -->
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    <a class="carousel-control-prev" (click)="anteriorInmueble()" href="#multi_item" role="button" data-slide="prev">
      <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
      <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
    </a>
    <a class="carousel-control-next" (click)="siguienteInmueble()" href="#multi_item" role="button" data-slide="next">
      <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
      <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
    </a>
  </div>
  </div>
  </div>
<ng-template #espera>Esperando datos...</ng-template>
</div>
```

Agradecería enermemente a la persona que me pueda ayudar, tengo horas en esto y no hallo una solución. gracias de antemano. Saludos!